# How to define a function to create functions in bash?

Tags: bash, function

### If a simple function factory is possible in bash?

For example: `function_factory func1 func2 func3` will create three functions that just have the passed names without doing anything.

These birthed functions should be exported with like `export -f function_name` to make sure they are available in the same environment of `function_factory` .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It could be something like that:

```
#!/bin/bash

function function_factory()
{
  while [ $# -ne 0 ]
  do
    eval "
    function $1()
{
  echo \"my name is $1\"
}
"
    shift
  done
}

function_factory fun1 fun2 fun3

fun1
fun3
```

output:

```
$ ./test 
my name is fun1
my name is fun3
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can use `eval`:

```
function generate_hello {
  eval "function say_hello_to_$1 { echo hello $1; }"
}
```

Then run it:

```
$ generate_hello world
$ say_hello_to_world
hello world
```

Answer (score 0):

This is about as minimal as I can get:

```
factory() { for f; do eval "$f() { :; }"; done; }
```

Then:

```
$ factory f{1..3}
$ type f1 f2 f3 f4
f1 is a function
f1 () 
{ 
    :
}
f2 is a function
f2 () 
{ 
    :
}
f3 is a function
f3 () 
{ 
    :
}
bash: type: f4: not found
```